# SmartGWT elements don't receive mouse events in Chrome & Safari

Tags: events, google-chrome, safari, mouse, smartgwt

I'm using smartGWT 2.5 to develope a module, my html start page is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test App</title>
<script> var isomorphicDir = "testApp/sc/"; </script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js"></script>
<script src="testApp/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js"></script>
<script>
currentSkin = "Enterprise";
document.write("<"+"script src=\"testApp/sc/skins/" + currentSkin + "/load_skin.js?isc_version=7.1.js\"><"+"/script>");
</script>
<script src="testApp/testApp.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

& this is my entryPoing implementation :

```
public class testApp extends SmartGwtEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setWidth100();
        form.setHeight100();

        ButtonItem loginButton = new ButtonItem("loginButton", "Login");  
        loginButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
                SC.say("Test!");
            }
        });
        form.setFields(loginButton);

        VLayout mainLayout = new VLayout();
        mainLayout.setHeight100();
        mainLayout.setWidth100();
        mainLayout.addMember(form);
        mainLayout.draw();
 }
}
```

My start page successfully initiates & shows the Login button of the created form, but the problem is that it does NOT work with mouse clicks(but works with keyboard key press), seems that the button does not receive any of mouse events.
I've this problem ONLY in chrome & safari, but it works correctly in firefox.
any idea?

Comment: Seems my browsers cause the problem, cause when I testes it on another pc(with same version of browsers) it worked without any problem

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't reproduce the problem (in any browser).  Things to look into:

1. Do you have a very old version of GWT, or perhaps more than one copy of GWT around?
2. Do you have additional inherits in your .gwt.xml for third-party libraries which might be interfering?
3. Do you have browser extensions in Safari or Chrome that are causing a problem?

If you can't immediately find the cause, do a clean install on a second machine just so that you can see that there's no problem with your code or SmartGWT, then return to troubleshooting what's special about the broken environment.

Answer (score 0):

AddBlock extension in Chrome caused this issue for me!